# Anyone know how to shorten the width of my button?

Tags: css

[The Link to the code](https://jsfiddle.net/9nek2sxw/)

I'm trying to re-size the 5x buttons that I have centered near the middle/bottom of the page.

How do I shorten (whilst keeping them in the same location) the buttons to half the width they currently are?

```
    /* Nav */
.nav li {
    list-style: none; 
    padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
  Color: White;
  Border: 3px Solid;
  border-color: black;
  font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
  background-color: #99CCFF;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

}

.nav li:hover {
  background: #117bff;
    cursor: pointer; 
    transition: background 1s; 
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Can you post HTML too?

Comment: If you use a (P/ DIV) tag for .nav class, then you have to use 

display: inline-block;

 property of that tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `display: inline-block` to your `nav` class and set the `width` to whatever you want.

For example:

```
.nav {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}
```

**EDIT**

To center the navigation menu you can use relative positioning, set `left` to 50% and translate by -50% in order to set the anchor point to the center of the element.

```
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,0);
position: relative;
```

Please note, I set the padding of `ul` to zero because by default the left padding is 40px.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e1tzz4og/3/)

Comment: This is great.. except it de-centralizes it!

If I do this, how do I keep it central?

You can now see my problem..

Comment: I added more details, take a look

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.nav li {
/*your code*/
display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

html { 
  background: url(http://www.desktopwallpaper2.com/photo/508ba1480284c-2306.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 100;
}

.container {
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 940px; 
 padding: 0 10px; 
}


/* Header */
.header {
  height: 800px;
  text-align: center; 
  color: white;
}


.header .container {
 position: relative;
 top: 200px;
}

.header h1 {
 font-size: 80px;
 line-height: 100px; 
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 80px;
}

@media (min-width:850px) {
 .header h1 {
  font-size: 120px;
 }
}

.header p {
 font-weight: 500;
 letter-spacing: 8px;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
 margin-top: 0;
}

a {
   background-color: Black; 
   border: 2px solid;
   padding: 10px;
   font-family: Impact;
     font-weight: normal;
   font-size: 20px;
   color: white;
   letter-spacing: 3px;
}
a:hover {
 background: #117bff;
 cursor: pointer; 
 transition: background .5s;  
}


/* Nav */

.nav ul {float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    }
.nav li {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom:10px;
 list-style: none; 
 padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
 text-align: center;
  Color: White;
  Border: 3px Solid;
  border-color: black;
  font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
  background-color: #99CCFF;
  letter-spacing: 1px;

    width: 200px;
   
  
    
  
}

.nav li:hover {
  background: #117bff;
 cursor: pointer; 
 transition: background 1s; 
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Main */
.main .container {
 margin: 80px auto;
  color: white;
}


/* Jumbotron */
.jumbotron {
 height: 600px; 
 text-align: right;
}

.jumbotron .container {
 position: relative;
 top: 220px;
}


/* Footer */
.footer { 
 font-size: 14px;
}

/* Media Queries */
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .header h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 64px;
  }

  .main, .jumbotron {
    padding: 0 30px;
  }

  .main img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <h1> Innovation Cloud </h1>
        <p> Connect Your Ideas Globally  </p>
        <a href="www.google.co.uk"> Learn More </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
      <div class="container">
        <ul>
          <li> Register </li>
          <li> Schedule </li>
          <li> Sponsors </li>
          <li> About </li>
          <li> Contact </li>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
      <div class="container">
        

        <h2>The Innovation Cloud Conference</h2>
        <p>Connect with the best minds across a wide range of industries to share ideas and brainstorm new solutions to challenging problems.</p>
        <p>Hear industry leaders talk about what worked (and what didn't) so that you can save time on your most challenging projects.</p>
         <p>Learn about the latest research and technologies that you can use immediately to invent the future.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Target `.nav` with following properties

```
.nav {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
}
```

and you might want to remove `.contaienr` (you don't need it). It has a `max-width` of `960px`.